# How to count the "white" correctly in mastermind guessing game in c?

Tags: c, arrays

“White" is the checking of correct number at wrong position.
But I don't know how to count it correctly.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h" 
#include "time.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int answer[4];
    int guess[4];
    int count = 0;

    srand(time(NULL)); 
    /*answer[0] = (rand() % 6)+1;
    answer[1] = (rand() % 6)+1;
    answer[2] = (rand() % 6)+1;
    answer[3] = (rand() % 6)+1;*/

    answer[0] = 3;
    answer[1] = 3;
    answer[2] = 5;
    answer[3] = 2;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", answer[0],  answer[1],  answer[2],  answer[3]);
    printf("          B W\n"); 

    do
    {
        int black = 0;
        int white = 0;
        count++;
        printf("Enter 4 numbers, this is your %d guess: ", count);
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &guess[0], &guess[1], &guess[2], &guess[3]);
        printf("\n%d %d %d %d\n", guess[0], guess[1], guess[2], guess[3]);

        int g2[2][6];

        for (int a = 0;a < 4;a++)
            g2[0][a]=answer[a];

        for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++)
            g2[1][i]=guess[i];

        if (answer[0]==guess[0])
            black++;
        if (answer[1]==guess[1])
            black++;
        if (answer[2]==guess[2])
            black++;
        if (answer[3]==guess[3])
            black++;

        if (answer[1]==guess[0] || answer[2]==guess[0] || answer[3]==guess[0])
            white++;
        if (answer[0]==guess[1] || answer[2]==guess[1] || answer[3]==guess[1])
            white++;
        if (answer[0]==guess[2] || answer[1]==guess[2] || answer[3]==guess[2])
            white++;
        if (answer[0]==guess[3] || answer[1]==guess[3] || answer[2]==guess[3])
            white++;

        if (black==4)
            white=0;

        g2[1][4]=black;
        g2[1][5]=white;

        for (int n = 0;n < 6;n++)
            printf(" %d",g2[1][n]); 

        printf("\n");
    }
    while (answer[0]!=guess[0] || answer[1]!=guess[1] ||
           answer[2]!=guess[2] || answer[3]!=guess[3]);

    printf("BINGO!!!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Update 2:

```
for (int slot=0;slot<4;slot++)
{
    if (guess[slot] == answer[slot]) 
        black++;
    else 
        for (int s=0;s<4;s++)
            if (s != slot) 
            {
                if (guess[slot] == answer[s]) 
                    white++;
                break;
            }
}
```

---

Update 3:

```
for (int x=0;x<4;x++)
flag[x]=0;

for (int slot = 0;slot < 4;slot++) 
{ 
    if (guess[slot] == answer[slot])  
        if (flag[slot]==1)
            black++; 
    else  
        for (int s=0;s < 4;s++) 
            if (s != slot)  
            { 
                if (guess[slot] == answer[s])
                    if (flag[s]==1)
                    {
                        white++; 
                        break; 
                    }
            } 
}
```

---

Update 4

```
for (int x=0;x<4;x++)
flag[x]=0;

for (int slot = 0;slot < 4;slot++) 
{ 
    if (guess[slot] == answer[slot])  {
        black++; 
        flag[slot]=1;
    }
else  
    for (int s=0;s < 4;s++)
        if (s != slot)
        { 
            if (guess[slot] == answer[s])  
            {
                white++; 
                flag[s]=1;
                break; 
            }
        } 
}
```

---

Update 5:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h" 
#include "time.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int answer[4];
    int guess[4];
    int flag[4];
    int count = 0;

    srand(time(NULL)); 
    /*answer[0] = (rand() % 6)+1;
    answer[1] = (rand() % 6)+1;
    answer[2] = (rand() % 6)+1;
    answer[3] = (rand() % 6)+1;*/

    answer[0] = 1;
    answer[1] = 2;
    answer[2] = 3;
    answer[3] = 4;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", answer[0],  answer[1],  answer[2],  answer[3]); 

    do
    {
        int black = 0;
        int white = 0;
        count++;
        printf("Enter 4 numbers, this is your %d guess: ", count);
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &guess[0], &guess[1], &guess[2], &guess[3]);

        int g2[2][6];

        for (int a = 0;a < 4;a++)
            g2[0][a]=answer[a];

        for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++)
            g2[1][i]=guess[i];

        for (int x=0;x<4;x++)
            flag[x]=0;

        for (int slot = 0;slot < 4;slot++) 
        { 
            if (guess[slot] == answer[slot])  
                black++; 
            else   
                for (int s=0;s < 4;s++)  
                    if (s != slot && guess[slot] == answer[s] && !flag[s]) 
                    {  
                        white++;  
                        flag[s]=1; 
                        break;  
                    }
        } 

        g2[1][4]=black;
        g2[1][5]=white;

        printf("Guess %d: ", count);

        for (int n = 0;n < 4;n++){
            printf(" %d",g2[1][n]);
        }

        printf(" Black: %d White: %d\n", g2[1][4], g2[1][5]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    while (answer[0]!=guess[0] || answer[1]!=guess[1] ||
           answer[2]!=guess[2] || answer[3]!=guess[3]);

    printf("BINGO!!!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested alternative (pseudocode):

```
white = 0;
black = 0;
for slot=0 to 3
  if guess[slot] == answer[slot]
    black++
  else
    for s=0 to 3
      if s != slot
        if guess[slot] == answer[s]
          white++
          break
```

**Update (detail)**

```
 else  
    for (int s=0;s < 4;s++) 
      if (s != slot && guess[slot] == answer[s] && !flag[s])
      { 
          white++; 
          flag[s]=1;
           break; 
      }
```

I think this should do it: We're checking for another slot that's not the current one, one that's not a perfect (black) match, and that hasn't been used before to flag a black or white.

Comment: Updated above, but still wrong in some case such as "3115". :(

Comment: Please make that a bit more specific: What was answer, guess and result pls?

Comment: The answer is "3352". If I guess "3115", result should be 1 Black and 1 White. If I guess "0033", result should be 0 Black and 
2 White.

Comment: Your update 2 is missing curly braces for the inner-most if, so it'll only check one slot per peg.

Comment: Like this? still not work:( if (guess[slot] == answer[s]) white++; { break; }

Comment: No: if (guess[slot] == answer[s]) { white++; break; }

Comment: No, like this: if (guess[slot] == answer[s]) { white++; break; } The indentation in Carl's post shows where the blocks are.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this really won't work after all. If you guessed 1123 and the code was 1234, it would give you a black and 3 whites, but there should only be 2 whites because the 1 has already been used for the black. You'd have to flag each peg in the answer as you used it, so you'd know not to use it again (and then, reset the flags before evaluating the next guess).

Comment: You could be right; I've forgotten the rules. Grandpa has a very nice set of rules, but we don't know if those are the rules from the OP's assignment.

Comment: Add an array called flag, with 4 places (int flag[4]). Before running your check, iterate through the array and set them all to 0 (false). In the places you currently have black++ and white++, replace these with an if statement that checks if flag[slot] (if you're checking for black) or flag[s] (if you're checking for white) is true. If this is the case, THEN you execute black++/white++, and at the same time, set the flag you just tested to 1 (true). Try to do it on your own first - you've already used everything you need to write this, and you'll learn more that way.

Comment: What is the meaning of "iterate through the array and set them all to 0 (false)." ?

Comment: Read "iterate" as "loop". Read "loop" as "construct a `for` loop that runs over the possible subscripts of the array (i.e. 0 to 3) and does something with the contents at that index."

Comment: for (int x=0;x<4;x++)
    flag[x]=0;

Like this?

Comment: Yes, you didn't correctly implement what Michael wrote. Look again and try a bit harder!

Comment: Sorry...I still have no idea about that, which parts should I modify? :(

Comment: Oh...still not work. I have updated my whole program, is it any wrong?

Comment: My mistake, sorry: There should be a "flag[x] = 1" underneath "black++".

Comment: "flag[slot] = 1"? It's seems really work now, thanks for all of you.:)

Answer (score 9):

Knuth answers this in *[The Computer as Master Mind](https://www.cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/teaching/cs3530/resources/knuth-mastermind.pdf)* and acknowledges that it's hard to define it exactly.  He suggests this:

1. Calculate the number of blacks by comparing each position in the answer with the same position in the current guess.
2. Calculate the number of whites plus blacks as below.
3. Subtract (1) from (2) to get the number of whites.

To calculate whites plus blacks:

1. Make two arrays, `ans` and `guess`, with a slot for each color.
2. For each color, populate `ans` with the number of pegs of that color in the answer.  Similarly, populate `guess` with the number of pegs of that color in the current guess.
3. Add up `min(ans[i], guess[i])` for each `i`.  This is whites plus blacks.

Comment: #4 is the number of misses, not the number of whites.

Comment: @Spookbuster - Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I cannot describe how well thought/written and helpful this answer is. Helped me A LOT

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for (int x=0;x<4;x++)
        flag[x]=guess[x]==answer[x]?1:0;

    for (int slot = 0;slot < 4;slot++) 
    { 
        if (guess[slot] == answer[slot])  
            black++; 
        else   
            for (int s=0;s < 4;s++)  
                if (!flag[s] && guess[slot] == answer[s]) 
                {  
                    white++;  
                    flag[s]=1; 
                    break;  
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment which states that Knuth provided a 4-step algorithm to determine the 
number of white and black pegs is incorrect in step 4.

Step 4 simply returns 4 - the number returned in step 3. step 4 returns the number of "misses", i.e. not a black or white peg.

Simply use step 3 to calculate the number of whites and backs in total; calculate the number of black pegs by using the simple

```
for i = 0 to 3:
   if(a[i] == g[i]) b = b + 1
```

Then of course whites = step 3 - number of black pegs (b).

Comment: tip: count the blacks in the same loop you use to construct the frequency table for step 3.